# Delete specific record from multiple duplicates in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

How do I delete specific record from multiple duplicates 
below is the table for eg

[image]

This is just one of the example and we have many cases like this. From this table I need to delete rank 2 and 3.

Kindly suggest me best way to identify duplicate records and delete the specific rows

Comment: which dbms you used

Comment: Please post data as text

Comment: can you specify which of the duplicates you want to remove?  the one with higher rank for example (does not match your question) - these are not exactly duplicates by the way since rank is different

Comment: Zaynul - I am using Microsoft SQL server 2012

Comment: Randy - I have just created an additional column as rank and wanted to explain my point that I need to delete rank no 2 and 3.

Here emp_ID - 169 has got two payroll which is incorrect. He should only have only one Payroll_no which is 431857 and emp_ID - 170 has got two payroll which is again incorrect and his payroll_no is 431858. So I need to delete the rank 2 and 3

Comment: Does it matter matter which one of the duplicated records to be deleted? For example, between Rank 1 and 2 why you suggested Rank 2 to be deleted, and between Rank 3 and 4 why is it Rank 3?

Comment: Is Rank even part of your data? Also, how do we know what Payroll_no is supposed to be associated with what emp_ID?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
delete
from <your table> t
where rank != (select top(rank)
              from <your table> tt
              where tt.emp_id = t.emp_id
               order by rank desc --put asc if you want to keep the lowest rank
               )
group by t.emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not encourage record deleting but this solution can help with expiring records or deleting them:

The table should have a unique ID and a field that allows you to identify that the record has been expired. If it does not, I recommend adding it to the table. You can creating a composite ID in your query but down the road you will wish you had these attributes.

Create a query that identifies every record where the RANK <> 1. This will be your subquery.

Write your UPDATE query

```
UPDATE A
SET [EXPIRE_DTTM] = GETDATE()
FROM *TableNameWithTheRecords* A
INNER JOIN (*SubQuery*) B ON A.UniqueID = B.UniqueID
```

**If you truly want to delete the records, use this:

```
DELETE FROM *TableNameWithTheRecords* 
WHERE *UniqueID* = (SELECT *UniqueID* FROM *TableNameWithTheRecords* WHERE RANK <> 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH tbl_alias AS
    (
       SELECT emp_ID,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY emp_ID ORDER BY emp_ID)
       FROM tblName
    )
    DELETE FROM tbl_alias WHERE RN > 1
```